# code blocks debug mode watches options greyed out

Tags: c, codeblocks

[image: screenshot]

I am new to c programming I need to show array elements in debug mode but I did right click array but options are greyed out as in image above

Comment: Are you trying to debug optimized code? Which compiler and what options did you give it?

Comment: It's either C or C++, can't be both at once.

Comment: How are you building your program? Did you remember to build an (unoptimized) debug version of your program?

Comment: i am using code blocks I don't know what  optimized code is